# How to pass function parameters to callback function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, callback, parameter-passing

I have created an OnClick handler function as below:

```
function onClickHandler(ID, doClick) {
  $('#' + ID).on('click', doClick);
}
```

I have created another function that will redirect after clicking a button:

```
function redirectPage(url) {
    window.location.href = url;
}
```

If I'm passing the url parameters as below, then I get only events of clicked button:

```
onClickHandler(CreateLODControlIds.BTN_CANCEL, redirectPage.bind(LODPage.DASHBOARD));
```

How can I pass the **url** parameters of **redirectPage** function in **onClickHandler** function?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **first** argument to `bind` is the `this` value.

The value you want to bind to the `url` parameter needs to be passed as the **second** argument to `bind`.